# Why is it that whenever I run this code I get a white rectangle on my screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('1000x1000')
window.configure(bg='black')

myCanvas = Canvas(window)
myCanvas.pack()

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName):
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

create_circle(100, 100, 50, myCanvas)


window.mainloop()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Why is there a white rectangle there? I am just trying to print a circle on a black canvas.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the white rectangle, but shouldn't `y0 = x - r` be `y0 = y - r` instead?

Comment: Instead of `myCanvas.pack()` use `myCanvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`

Comment: The white box is actually the `tkinter.Canvas` and the black is your window. At least that's my theory

Comment: @TheLizzard Yeah that seems to be right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs that are causing your problem:

1.Any default canvas's color are white.

2.The canvas also has a default highlight boarder which is also white.

To solve both of these problems you can change:

```
myCanvas = Canvas(window)
```

to

```
myCanvas = Canvas(window, bg='black',highlightthickness=0)
```

Then the white rectangle will disappear

if you want to keep the highlight boarder you can also change the color of the boarder using `highlightbackground="black"`

or any other desired color.

Finally, if you want to change the circle's color because the circle blends into the canvas color add: `outline="white"`
to when you make the oval